# Foreach : Filter Folder and match stingue and us timespan

Tags: powershell

I have:

```
    >cls
get-childitem -path '.\k*' -Recurse –Directory | sort-object -property name -descending | format-table name, CreationTime, LastWriteTime
```

I get:

```
KBBK         27/05/2021 09:31:43 27/05/2021 09:31:43
KBBKQ        27/05/2021 09:31:43 27/05/2021 09:31:43
KBK          27/05/2021 09:31:43 27/05/2021 09:31:43
KBKB         27/05/2021 09:31:43 27/05/2021 09:31:43
KBKN         27/05/2021 09:31:43 27/05/2021 09:31:43
KBKP         27/05/2021 09:31:43 27/05/2021 09:31:43
```

at now: us timespan to get day, hour minute:

```
>$decimalHour=
$day=[Math]::Truncate($decimalday))
$hour=[Math]::Truncate($decimalHour)
$minute=($decimalHour - $hour) * 60
$minute=[Math]::Truncate($minute)
$date=[datetime]::Parse("$day`:$hour`:$minute`)
$date.Day
$date.Hour
$date.Minute
$date.ToLongTimeString()
```

Thanks for your help
Arnold

Comment: Pls: filter folder also match 'run"

Comment: I don't understand the question.. Why so difficult? Since `CreationTime` and `LastWriteTime` properties are already `DateTime` objects, you could simply do `CreationTime.ToLongTimeString()`

Comment: nks Theo: cls

"kbbbkb",  # 2 29.05.2021 - 15h50; fin 29.05.2021 - 22h23
"kbbbkn",  # 3 29.05.2021 - 22h30; fin 30.05.2021 - 12h36
"kbbbkq",  # 4 30.05.2021 - 12h37; fin 30.05.2021 - 19h21
"kbbbkr",  # 5 30.05.2021 - 19h22; fin 31.05.2021 - 07h45
this is math (pronominal) wath is the diff time to du! (with the folder-name. Match string: run (end) Arnold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would want a colum TimeDiff where the difference between the LastWriteTime and CreationTime of the object is displayed.

In that case, you can do this:

```
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path '.\k*' -Recurse –Directory | 
    Sort-Object -Property Name -Descending |
    ForEach-Object {
        # get a TimeSpan object by subtracting the two dates from the DirectoryInfo object
        $diff = $_.LastWriteTime - $_.CreationTime
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Name          = $_.Name
            CreationTime  = $_.CreationTime
            LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
            # format the time difference anyway you like                              
            # here, as demo create something like '2d11h37m'  (2 days, 11 hours, 37 minutes)
            TimeDiff      = '{0}d{1}h{2}m' -f $diff.Days, $diff.Hours, $diff.Minutes
            # or something like '2.11:37'  (2 days, 11 hours, 37 minutes)
            # TimeDiff      = '{0}.{1:D2}:{2:D2}' -f $diff.Days, $diff.Hours, $diff.Minutes
        }
    }

# display on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to CSV file if you like
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'Path\To\The\Output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hello Theo

Manny thanks for your reply

Yes!

    KRKQ                                   27/05/2021 09:33:09 27/05/2021 09:33:09 0d0h0m
    KRKQ                                   24/05/2021 00:39:41 27/05/2021 17:57:22 3d17h17m
    KRKPP                                  28/05/2021 19:13:06 28/05/2021 19:31:37 0d0h18m
    KRKP                                   24/05/2021 00:39:41 27/05/2021 17:57:22 3d17h17m

Just i have forget:
1. Folder (ist ok)
the second condition is:
**2. If folder is on the end
please -match for string "run"
inside the folder**
Manny thank's Sir!
Arnold

Comment: @Arenas Glad it works for you. However, what do you mean by _"If folder is on the end"_ and what is _"-match for string "run" inside the folder"_? You mean the last folder of the whole iteration? Is "run" in the NAME of that folder? Something like `Get-ChildItem -Path '.\k*'run*` perhaps?

Comment: Hello Sir if the probleme is solved = the word "run" is inside the folder. (donne). I m so sorry sir! Arnold

Comment: Sir: the propriete from the folder have "run" inside and: Info from the propriete
the folder. (KBBBKN)
Open with "jEdit"
Editeur de txt
for scripte

bname     KBBBKN
passdone     902
maxbcwply     39
maxbczply    156
cstotal  4859339
maxsolw      155
maxsolz      156
wmopen    1282453830
wnopen    8269881744
zmopen    1192607874
znopen    7641322920